# Access Array Inside Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I have a javascript object and I want to map through one of its properties which is an array. But for some reason when I map through it or even call .length on the property which I know is an array it treats the property as if it's not an array.

Object is being created from an axios get request in an asynchronous object.

```
useEffect(() => {

   async function fetchData() {
            const dummyData = await axios.get(
                'http://localhost:3000/data',
            );
            dummyData.data.videos.map(video => {
                return (
                    setCurrentEdition(video.currentEdition[0])
                );
            });
        }
        fetchArtPiece();
        return () => console.log('clean artPiece detail page');
    }, []);
```

```
currentEdition: {
  videoAssociated: {id: "oYu5J4TQbJ728c45ExWopZicY9LrCxNNTEZ3"}
  bids: []
  id: "Kr3fjeo51"
  owners: (2) [{…}, {…}]
}
```

All im trying to do for now is .map() and it throws an undefined error

```
currentEdition.owners.map(owners => console.log(owners))
```

even when i check currentEdition.owners.length it throws an undefined error and when I log currentEdition.owners the proto: is an array and it has the square brackets and everything so why is this not being treated as an array when I try to operate on it?

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Is the object being loaded dynamically? I think we need to see some more code.

Comment: What does `Array.isArray(currentEdition.owners)` return? It's possible that it's only an array-like object or it's being modified at runtime.

Comment: Show how you're creating the object. I suspect it's being created asynchronously, and you're trying to access the property before it's filled in.

Comment: To check that what you are logging really exist at the time you log instead of in the future do not `console.log(currentEdition)` but instead `console.log(JSON.stringify(currentEdition, null, 2))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses I am creating the object asynchronously this object is being created from data pulled from the web in an asynchronous useEffect hook. Simply passed in to a state object from an axios get request. Thanks again

Comment: So where exactly are you trying to use `currentEdition.owners.map(owners => console.log(owners))`?

Comment: For now just logging In my jsx like this:
 ```
<Grid item xs={7}>
 {console.log(currentEdition.owners.length)}
</Grid>
```

Comment: *"Thanks for the quick responses I am creating the object asynchronously"* Well than you are trying to eat your pizza before it is delivered to your house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you are working with asynchronous data you should always make sure that you have your data and then start playing with it around.

So to fix this you need to make a condition for your JSX like this:

```html
<Grid item xs={7}> {Array.isArray(currentEdition?.owners) && console.log(currentEdition.owners.length)} </Grid>
```